# Implement Firebase into Xamarin.Forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

How can I use Firebase into Xamarin.Forms

Seems that the only "official" way is through [Xamarin.GooglePlayServicesComponent](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/), but what if i want to deploy my app for iOS or UWP?

Answer (score 0):

For ios you have [GoogleApisForiOSComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents). Also, you can find the components in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xamarin%20firebase%20ios)